# How to access children of included layout in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have custom iconified Button, which I want to use in my project, but I need to access its children to set texts in XML. How to achieve this?

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/leaveBtn"
    layout="@layout/iconified_button"
    style="@style/button_rounded_colorized"
 />
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/button_rounded_colorized">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buttonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I want to be able to change button style in included layout. I don't want to have static style in `iconified_button` layout xml.

UPDATE:

Made custom class extending `LinearLayout` inflating layout above and set `Button` text and `ImageView` icon via custom parameters made in `attrs.xml` which are accessible in XML.

```
<com.project.utils.IconifiedButton
   android:id="@+id/leaveBtn"
   style="@style/button_rounded_colorized"
   app:buttonText="@string/button_text_2"
   app:buttonIco="@drawable/arrow"
 />
```

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="IconifiedButton">
        <attr name="buttonText" format="string" />
        <attr name="buttonIco" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Button button = findViewById(R.id.leaveButton)` (I'm not sure if `R.id.leaveButton` is enough, or you have to set `id` for your `LinearLayout`) and then use `button.findViewById(R.id.buttonText)` to get to your `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't what you are looking for.
To have *"iconified Button"* you could use a simple [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with the **`app:icon`** attribute, instead of 2 views:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        android:text="Button"
        ../>
```

[image]

You can set the text using a simple:

```
MaterialButton button = findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
button.setText("...");
```

You can customize at runtime the style(background color,text color,Icon color and drawable, stroke, corner radius). Check the official doc for the details.

Instead in your example just use:

```
TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.buttonText);
textview.setText("....");
```

Comment: MaterialButton library is not working for me for some reason. Missing styles. But I figured it out. I made class extending LinearLayout and inflated this xml, added custom attributes to `attrs.xml` and now I can access and set children attributes in xml.

Comment: missing styles? Do you mean that you have switch to material theme? In any case you can also use the `android:drawableStart=""` attribute inside the standard `Button` to achieve the same behaviour

Comment: Yes, drawableStart is not that good because icon is pushed to very edge of the button and you have to add padding manually to position it to center. Custom Class with layout is the best for now but thanks